# numpy dot returns invalid values for large arrays when using scipy.linalg.blas.sgemm

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, blas

I'm trying to compute A • A<sup>T</sup>:

```py
# These are my dummy values for testing
A = np.ones((150000,265),dtype=np.float32, order='F')
A_T = np.ones((265, 150000),dtype=np.float32, order='F')

out = scipy.linalg.blas.sgemm(alpha=1.0, a=A, b=A_T)
```

Two minutes later:

```py
In [7]: out
Out[7]: 
array([[ 265.,  265.,  265., ...,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 265.,  265.,  265., ...,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 265.,  265.,  265., ...,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       ..., 
       [ 265.,  265.,  265., ...,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 265.,  265.,  265., ...,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 265.,  265.,  265., ...,    0.,    0.,    0.]])

In [10]: out.shape
Out[10]: (150000, 150000)
```

Notice the zeros?  I'm lost... I've tried using 64bit floats and get the same output.
From 35468 on, the array is zeros.

```py
In [39]: out[0,35468]
Out[39]: 0.0

In [9]: scipy.__version__
Out[9]: '0.12.1'
```

***UPDATE/EDIT:***

I am fairly sure, that np.dot is calling the *gemm methods themselves.

```py
In [1]: A = np.ones((150000,265), dtype=np.float32, order='F')

In [2]: A_T = np.ones((265, 150000),dtype=np.float32, order='F')

In [3]: out = A.dot(A_T)

In [4]: out.shape
Out[4]: (150000, 150000)

In [5]: out
Out[5]: 
array([[ 265.,  265.,  265., ...,  265.,  265.,  265.],
   [ 265.,  265.,  265., ...,  265.,  265.,  265.],
   [ 265.,  265.,  265., ...,  265.,  265.,  265.],
   ..., 
   [   0.,    0.,    0., ...,    0.,    0.,    0.],
   [   0.,    0.,    0., ...,    0.,    0.,    0.],
   [   0.,    0.,    0., ...,    0.,    0.,    0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: What are variables roi and roiT?

Comment: From the [docs for scipy.linalg.blas](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.12.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.blas.html)
"__Warning__: These functions do little to no error checking. It is possible to cause crashes by mis-using them, so prefer using the higher-level routines in scipy.linalg."  As `np.dot` can do matrix multiplication, why have you chosen to use `scipy.linalg.blas.dgemm`?

Comment: For me, `np.dot(A, A_T)` is more accurate and faster.  I had to reduce the size since your example data destroyed my computer :P

Comment: I'm pretty sure taht np.dot is calling these exact blas routines. I had the same failure with np.dot. I'm rerunning now to confirm and will update the original post.

Comment: @John1024 Thanks for asking John. I originally started with sgemm b/c I wanted to conserve memory by not having to create A and A_T, since *gemm has the 'trans_a' and 'trans_b' arguments. Now, I don't think it matters as the two float32 arrays don't take that much space.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine your example dies with the `Memory Error`, same for `np.dot(A, A.T)`.

On reducing the matrix size, it produces a correct result.

To debug it further, try using the Fortran BLAS call directly, without python. If it passes, consider [filing a bug in the scipy tracker](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues?state=open).

As a side note, from scipy 0.13 onwards you can use `syrk`.

Comment: I agree...I need to run the blas from fortran or try cblas directly. I've never compiled fortran before beyong "hello world"...i guess I start learning :)  Keep an eye out for new threads on that :)

Comment: well, all you need here is not much more than a hello world :-)